# fullcalendar remember user option eg. month/week/day in cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

How could I modify the [fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/) plugin so that this saves the different click methods `dayClick` etc in a cookie? The next time this calendar is opened if would default to the user preference.

Already using the cookie plugin: https://raw.github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/jquery.cookie.js

Update of working cookie code following answer:

```
var calendarView = (!$.cookie('calendarDefaultView')) ? 'month' : $.cookie('calendarDefaultView');  
$calendar.fullCalendar({
    defaultView: calendarView,
    viewDisplay: function(view){
        $.cookie('calendarDefaultView', view.name, {expires:7, path: '/'});
    },
```

Comment: In version 2 I had to change viewDisplay to viewRender for this to work. ie. viewRender: function( view , element) { ....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The two fullcalendar methods you need are:

```
//pull viewName from the cookie or set as default
var viewName='month'; //or basicWeek, basicDay, agendaWeek, agendaDay
$("#fullcalendar").fullCalendar( 'changeView', viewName );
```

and

```
$('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar({
        viewDisplay: function( view )
        {
           //save your cookie here, it's triggered each time the view changes
        }
});
```

This should put you on the right path. I didn't look at saving the cookie b/c I think you have that under control.

Comment: If you need more detail just ask...I might need this functionality too in the future.

Comment: Worked perfect thanks. I wanted to keep the cookie value clean and simple to I used: `view.name`. Updated my question with working code for cookie.

Comment: Nice clean solution! Glad I could help.

Comment: WIth fullcalendar v2, use the `viewRender` callback